# Use typdefs of STL classes like map, list etc

Tags: c++, list, stl, dictionary, types

In a current project I am programming C++, and I am using the STL classes map, set and list quite often. Now I am interested if there is a way to clean up some code by using the internal data types. For example:

```
std::map<uint64_t, std::list<int32_t> > mymap;
// add something to the map
for (std::map<uint64_t, std::list<int32_t> >::const_iterator it = mymap.begin (); it != mymap.end (); it++) {
    // iterate here
}
```

My question is if I could replace `std::map<uint64_t, std::list<int32_t> >::const_iterator` e.g. by `mymap.const_iterator`, but that does not compile. To quote g++ here:

```
error: invalid use of ‘std::map<long long unsigned int, std::list<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::less<long long unsigned int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const long long unsigned int, std::list<int, std::allocator<int> > > > >::const_iterator’
```

Any ideas of how to do this? Or is it not possible?

Comment: You mean `mymap::const_iterator` ?

Comment: Use this _std::map<uint64_t, std::list<int32_t> > mymap_ as a typedef rather than the iterator.

Comment: @KennyTM: mymap::const_iterator does not compile.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
typedef std::map<uint64_t, std::list<int32_t> > mymaptype;
mymaptype mymap;
for (mymaptype::const_iterator ...
```

Comment: OK, of course type definitions are working. But isn't there a technique to automatically get the type of this map as it already has been defined once?

Comment: @mreichelt: In C++0x you can use the `auto` keyword: `for (auto it = mymap.begin();...`.

Comment: In c++0x you'd use `auto`. In c++03, no.

Comment: Ok, so it seems what I want to do is not possible (for me). Therefore I am marking this as the correct answer, although Xeo's answer also is correct (I would mark two answers if I could). Thanks for helping! :-)

Answer (score 3):

If your compiler supports the `auto` keyword, use that. Eg. Visual Studio 2010 and GCC 4.3 and above support it.

```
std::map<uint64_t, std::list<int32_t> > myMap;
for(auto it = myMap.begin(); it != myMap.end(); ++it){
  // iterate...
}
```

Comment: This of course would be the best way to go - but the project I am using does not use the C++0x standard, and I don't like to add this standard just for my own extension. Apart from typedef and auto, is there no other way to get the type?

Answer (score -1):

This works just fine for me

```
typedef std::map<uint64_t, std::list<int32_t> >::iterator my_map;
std::map<uint64_t, std::list<int32_t> > mymap;
for (my_map it = mymap.begin (); it != mymap.end (); it++)
{
    // iterate here
}
```

Comment: If this works fine for you, then your compiler is funky. You should at least have to use `my_map::iterator` there.

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y: my_map is typedef'ed to the iterator type. Above code'll work, it's just weird.